# Laravel 5.1/Homestead PDOException

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5.1, homestead

I am learning Laravel and migrations. I have installed Homestead successfully and everything is be up and running — MySQL included — until I give my first

```
php artisan migrate
```

and the shell outputs

```
  [PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

so I connect to the virtual machine via SSH and try to install the PHP extensions required to work with the database, but `apt-get` detects I have the latest driver version already installed. Then I check to see if PDO is working, so I type `php -i | grep PDO` and everything looks good:

```
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, pgsql, sqlite
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

I am out of ideas, what could possibly go wrong?